# Populate depenent select values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

Consider this Javascript array of objects.

```
$scope.keyName = [{
  'key': 'stringName',
  'type': 'String',
  'query': ['equalTo', 'notEqualTo', 'contains', 'startsWith', 'exists', 'doesNotExist']
}, {
  'key': 'email',
  'type': 'String',
  'query': ['equalTo', 'notEqualTo', 'contains', 'startsWith', 'exists', 'doesNotExist']
}, {
  'key': 'username',
  'type': 'String',
  'query': ['equalTo', 'notEqualTo', 'contains', 'startsWith', 'exists', 'doesNotExist']
}, {
  'key': 'buzzInAccess',
  'type': 'Boolean',
  'query': ['exists', 'doesNotExist']
}]
```

I was trying something like this

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="a" class="form-control" ng-model="keyName">
    <option ng-repeat="x in keyName track by $index" value="[[x]]">[[x.key]]</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!--Query Parameter-->
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="search" ng-model="searchParam.query" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="y in keyName track by $index" value="y">[[y.query]]</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The second select has all the values in array form.

What I want to achieve is show two `select` dropdown. First select with `key` and second select has corresponding `query` values populated. This is done in Angular. How can I populate second select depending upon the corresponding `key` value.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried updating scope variable with the value of object.query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ng-options`. Following is the code depicting the same.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zey843xv/)

```
<div>
  <select ng-options="p.key for p in keyName" ng-model='selectedKey'></select>
  <select ng-options="p for p in selectedKey.query" ng-model='selectedQuery'></select>
  <span>{{keyName}}</span>
</div>
```